# How do I distribute my app to test devices using Xcode Server?

Tags: xcode, xcode-server

I would like to distribute my app to test devices using Xcode Server. What should I be doing to achieve this? Is there documentation or help on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This might be the place you want to start my friend: 
https://developer.apple.com/testflight/
If that is too exact I would strongly suggest that you google Apple developer guide and that's exactly what should help you. They have a lot to offer someone who has a specific task to do regarding apps.

Comment: This does not do what I am looking for.